# error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I am new to using templates with structures. My main goal is to have auto variable inside structure.

More importantly, I am using a library function of Funct.Methd(const auto, &Handler). Here as you can see, in the place of the first argument, I would like to pass (based on some criteria) any const auto variable that is created by the user. I am expecting to have more than 20 variables, based on some criteria any 5 would be used.

After doing some research, I found that I can use template for this purpose. Please find the sample code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct FTmr {
    T query;
};

int main()
{
    FTmr<T> df;    
}
```

I am getting an error `use of undeclared identifier 'T'` when using the template with structures. First I need to resolve the above error and then I wanted to use const auto.

I was hoping to instantiate FTmr with df name and then access query variable.

```
df.query=<<const auto value>>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you expect `FTmr<T> df; ` to do?

Comment: Where is your `T` from in `main()`...

Comment: I was hoping to instantiate FTmr with df name and then access query variable. df.query=<<const auto value>>

Comment: You have to substitute a real type for `T`. Like `FTmr<int> df;` or `FTmr<std::string> df;` or something.

Comment: Thanks @FredLarson for quick response, but I wanted to use const auto variable type for query variable. So if I replace T with const auto then I am getting error: auto not allowed in template argument

Comment: What do you expect it to deduce the type from?

Comment: You really need to read the book, sorry. Looks you have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: "I am new to using templates with structures" - I'd say it seems that you haven used templates with anything. Otherwise `FTmr<T>` would not be something you would expect to work at all. I would suggest looking into the topic of templates in general.

Comment: @TheVoyager: It also sounds like you have a misunderstanding of what `auto` does in C++.  `auto` means the compiler figures out the type for you. _But it still has a specific type_. It merely saves you from typing out the exact type yourself.

Comment: The question was unclear; I hope it's clearer now with the additional info. Regarding the answer — I suspect that you need to use `decltype(whatever)` for your template argument. Maybe more knowledgeable people can elaborate how.

Comment: Edits notwithstanding, you still need to read your C++ book's chapter on templates to get a basic understanding of what they are and what they can do, before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables in C++ have fixed types from the moment they are declared.

Templates are not types.  Templates are instructions on how to make a type.

A `const auto` variable has a type determined by what you assign to it:

```
const auto x = foo();
```

the type of `x` is fixed, it is deduced by the fixed return type of `foo()`.  The language just finds it for you.

A member of a struct is a variable.  It must have its type determined within the struct the moment it is declared.  You cannot defer its type until it is used.

```
struct Foo {
  static const auto x = 3;
};
```

that works because `x`'s type can be determined at the spot where `x` is declared.

In short, `const auto` doesn't work like that.

It may be possible to do what you really want to do, but it might be *hard*, and you probably lack the vocabulary to describe what it is you really want.  My advice would be to not fight against the language and go with a fixed type.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk for the detailed answer, it is really helpful. I am using clang AST function of MatchFinder.addMatcher(<const auto>, &Handler). Here as you can see, in the place of the first argument, I would like to pass (based on some criteria) any const auto variable that is created by the user. I am expecting to have more than 20 variables, based on some criteria any 5 would be used. This is my scenario, can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

What is `T` in main? You have to define it before using it. The previous `T` is scoped to the `templated struct` above. Also you cannot use that way; You have to instantiate the templated-struct this way:

```
FTmr<int> df;
FTmr<char> df;
// ...
```

T is the templated parameter which means as if passing a variable to a function it means passing the `type` instead. So the compile will create an instance of the struct with the type passed int.

- Functions take variables as parameters this way:

  ```
  void foo(int x, char y, double z, struct foo& the foo, long* pBar, ...);
  ```
- Templates take `types` instead as parameters:

  ```
  template< class T> void Power(T& x);

  template < typename U, typename V>
  class Baz{
      U _uval;
      V _vVal;
  };
  ```

So when instantiating the templated class / function the compiler will create an instance with that type:

```
    Baz<int, std::string> bistr;
```

An instance created by the compiler:

```
class Baz{
    int _uval;
   std:: string _vVal;
};
```

- Keep in mind that at compile time there is no template or type T but instead a specific version of the class is created.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: Templates don't read your mind. You still have to tell them what to do.**

`const auto` is not a "variable type". `auto` is a keyword that enables the *deduction* of a type from some information that you give it. For example, it knows that `5` is an `int` (because them's the rules), so `auto x = 5;` is possible.

In this case, you simply did not give it any information. How do you think it should know what to use for `T`? *We* don't even know! Do you know? What should `query` be? What should it do? Think it through, then let your computer know what you've decided.